# how to: echo mysql_query($show_tables) to standard output?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this php script that gets run by a cronjob everyday:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Could not select database: " . mysql_error()) ;

//create backup table with current date concatenated to the table name
$create_table = "set @c=concat('create table    rc_profile_table_backup_',date_format(now(),'%Y_%m_%d'))";
$prepare = "prepare stmt from @c";
$execute = "execute stmt";
$deallocate = "deallocate prepare stmt";

mysql_query($create_table);
mysql_query($prepare);
mysql_query($execute);
mysql_query($deallocate);

echo $sql11 = "insert rc_profile_table_backup_".mktime(date("y"),date("m"),date("d"))."select * from   rc_profile_table"."\n";
```

how can i achieve the insert above? I run this script in a cronjob so it must pick up the the table name with the current date and do the insert. how am i going to know the current date?

thanks

Comment: use datatype `current_timestamp`

Comment: cant think that this is correct: insert rc_profile_table_backup_".current_timestamp()."select * from   rc_profile_table"."\n";

Comment: what `create table    rc_profile_table_backup_',date_format(now(),'%Y_%m_%d')` this do exactly???

Comment: i have the comment right above the command stating what the command does

Comment: but i really never seen such syntax

Comment: You should really use mysqli or PDO instead of the old mysql extension in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Writing to stdout in PHP

You can use the stream wrapper `php://stdout` or the predefined `STDOUT` (which is the prefered way):

```
fwrite(STDOUT, "My text to write to stdout");
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

#### Moving some logic of your code to php

Your php would look something like this:

```
$tableName = "rc_profile_table_backup_" . date("Y_m_d");
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `{$tableName}` ..."); // insert your schema here
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `{$tableName}` SELECT * FROM `rc_profile_table`");
```

#### Other issues with your code

Don't use unnecessary string inserts:

```
("$db_name")
```

can be written as

```
($db_name)
```

The whole process of preparing, executing and deallocating should be made with the appropriate mysql classes (mysqli, PDO) and not in your own code. They do all this work for you.

Comment: thanks very much! but how am i going to insert into the table not knowing what the date is? the table is there, it exists, but i need to insert into it from my main table so i can back it up?

Comment: Fetch the date, create the table with a single query in PHP and run the `INSERT INTO .. SELECT *`. Just don't try to make it all in one query - it doesn't matter. It only makes things more complicated and you have nearly no performance gain.

Comment: oops yes quite right ("$db_name") should be ($db_name).. what would my insert statement then look like? that is the question..i have the table but everything is automated so must somehow get date dynamically and do: insert rc_profile_table_backup_".currdate(date("y"),date("m"),date("d"))."select * from   rc_profile_table; ? thanks

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include some lines of php to show you the way.

Comment: Why not simply use `echo` to write to stdout?!

Comment: With `echo` you have several problems: first, you only get the result as soon as the script is finished and you cannot distinguish your output between STDOUT and ERROUT. STDOUT is the "official" way to go ([PHP tells you to do it like this in their docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)). The problem (blemish) with `echo` in CLI is described in more detail here: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-command-line-1/